# How to see TCP, IP headers in my HTTP proxy?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, http-proxy, packets

I have a forking HTTP proxy implemented on my Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 with the following scheme (I'm reporting the essential code and pseudocode just to show the concept):

1. `socketClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)`;
2. `bind(socketClient,(struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))`;
3. `listen(socketClient, 50)`;
4. `newSocket = accept(socketClient, (struct sockaddr*)&cliAddr, sizeof(cliAddr))`;
5. get request from client, parse it to resolve the requested hostname in an IP address;
6. `fork()`, open connection to remote server and deal the request;
7. child process: if it is a `GET` request, send original request to server and while server is sending data, send data from server to client;
8. child process: else if it is a `CONNECT` request, send string `200 ok` to client and poll both client socket descriptor and server socket descriptor with `select()`; if I read data from server socket, send this data to client; else if I read data from client socket, send this data to server.

The good thing is that this proxy works, the bad thing is that now I must collect statistics; this is bad because I'm working on a level where I can't get the data I'm interested in. I don't care about the payload, I just need to check in IP and TCP headers the flags I care about.

For example, I'm interested in:

- connection tracking;
- number of packets sent and received.

As for the first, I would check in the TCP header the SYN flag, SYN/ACK and then a last ACK; as for the second, I would just do +1 to a counter of mine every time a `char buffer[1500]` is filled with data when I `send()` or `recv()` a full packet.

I realized that this is not correct: `SOCK_STREAM` doesn't have the concept of packet, it is just a continuous stream of bytes! The `char buffer[1500]` I use at point 7. and 8. has useful statistic, I may set its capacity to 4096 bytes and yet I couldn't keep track of the TCP packets sent or received, because TCP has *segments*, not *packets*.

I couldn't parse the `char buffer[]` looking for SYN flag in TCP header either, because IP and TCP headers are stripped from the header (because of the level I'm working on, specified with `IPPROTO_TCP` flag) and, if I understood well, the `char buffer[]` contains only the payload, useless to me.

So, if I'm working on a too high level, I should go lower: once I saw a simple `raw` socket sniffer where an `unsigned char buffer[65535]` was cast to `struct ethhdr, iphdt, tcphdr` and it could see *all* the flags of *all* the headers, all the stats I'm interested in!

After the joy, the disappointment: since `raw` sockets work on a low level they don't have some concepts vital to my proxy; `raw` sockets can't `bind`, `listen` and `accept`; my proxy is listening on a fixed port, but `raw` sockets don't know what a port is, it belongs to the TCP level and they `bind` to a specified interface with `setsockopt`.

So, if I'd `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, ntohs(ETH_P_ALL))` I should be able to parse the buffer where I `recv()` and `send()` at .7 and .8, but I should use `recvfrom()` and `sendto()`...but all this sounds quite messy, and it envolves a nice refactoring of my code.

How can I keep intact the structure of my proxy (`bind, listen, accept` to a fixed port and interface) and increase my line of vision for IP and TCP headers?

Comment: I'll edit the question for more details.

Comment: It is very unlikely that you get any UDP with a HTTP proxy at all.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a dedicated sniffer, such as wireshark? You could sniff all traffic on a specific interface and then filter by protocol and port numbers. You can also write your own sniffer using the raw  socket approach: http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-c-linux/

Comment: You have created requirements that seem to be at significant odds with the design of your project.  Are you sure you need to know about specific packet traffic?  Why do you think you need that?  If your application is the only traffic bound to this interface you could map to the local interface and query it for these statistics.

Comment: Alternatively, you could hack the kernel code to print of export all the things you want, assuming you will have permissions to run a custom kernel with your app (a loadable module might also be sufficient, depends on what exactly you want to do).

Comment: This code is part of my thesis, I may use some external libraries but not a full complete program as Wireshark.
Yes @SteffenUllrich you are right, no UDP required, I think I included too much in my header inspection XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to open a raw socket in, for example, another thread of your application. Sniff all traffic and filter out the relevant packets by addresses and port numbers. Basically you want to implement your own packet sniffer:

```
int sniff()
{
    int sockfd;
    int len;
    int saddr_size;
    struct sockaddr saddr;
    unsigned char buffer[65536];

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
    while (1) {
        saddr_size = sizeof(saddr);
        len = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, &saddr, &saddr_size);
        if (len < 0) {
            perror("recvfrom");
            close(sockfd);
            return -1;
        }

        // ... do the things you want to do with the packet received here ...
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

You can also bind that raw socket to a specific interface if you know which interface is going to be used for the proxy's traffic. For example, to bind to "eth0":

```
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eth0", 4);
```

Use `getpeername()` and `getsockname()` function calls to find the local and remote addresses and port numbers of your TCP connections. You'll want to filter the packets by those.